# Is there a set non-countable around zero but countable elsewhere?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is there a set $A$ such that for every $a,r>0$ we have that $(0,r)\cap A$ is non-countable but $(a,a+r)\cap A$ is countable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. Because $$(0,r) \cap A = \left( \bigcup_{n>0} \left(\frac{1}{n}, r\right) \right) \cap A =  \bigcup_{n>0} \left(\left(\frac{1}{n}, r\right) \cap A  \right)$$

But a countable union of countable set is countable, hence if every $(\frac{1}{n}, r) \cap A$ is countable, $(0,r)\cap A$ is countable

Comment: It's nice to know that this answer uses the axiom of choice, and it is in fact consistent to have such $A$ in some models where the axiom of choice fails (very badly, though).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: where does the AoC come in?

Comment: @Harry: I think the proof of "countable union of countable sets is countable" uses it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It doesn't, does it? Given the countable collection of countable sets, $A=\{A_i : i \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\}$, where each ${A_i}=\{ a_{i_j} : j \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\}$, isn't it enough to consider the surjective map $f: \{1/n + m : n,m \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\} \to \cup A$ given by $f(m+1/n)=a_{n_m}$? Then since the domain is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, $\cup A$ is countable.

Comment: @Carlos: If I've understood correctly, the problem is with assigning the indices. Your set $A$ is constructed with them in place.

Comment: But there exist, by definition of the countability of $A_i$, a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $A_i$, so I don't think you need AC to assign the indices, as you have an explicit way to do this. $a_{i,j} = \varphi_{A_i}(j)$, and $\varphi_{A_i}$ exist by definition

Comment: @Carlos: If you have a countable set, then there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ ways to put it in bijection with $\Bbb N$. These ways are completely arbitrary in the most case. So if you have infinitely many countable sets, how can you find a uniform way to match each one with $\Bbb N$? You can't. And there are models of set theory where the axiom of choice fails, and countable unions of countable sets are in fact uncountable.

Comment: So which one of you is right? Both convince me but your positions are opposite.

Comment: @CarlosPinzón : He is right : while there is no problem to assign one bijection to each $A_i$ one by one, you need the axiom of countable choice to do this to all $A_i$ at the same time

Comment: Got it, thanks.